# Small group tour operator for Southern USA trip

Tags: usa, tours, new-orleans

I'm looking into going on a tour of the South of the US, taking in places like Nashville, Memphis and New Orleans. I'd like to go with a small group of young-ish people (I'm 27) but am not after the "gap year" type trip that you seem to get when searching for 18-35s holidays. I also don't want to end up with a load of pensioners!

How can I find a tour operator that caters to this age group?

Comment: @Abbie why go with a guided tour? Do it with a backpack and a shoestring budget with a friend. You'll meet more interesting characters that way.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum Just looking into all options. I like the idea of getting some kind of local knowledge, whether that be by a tour guide (which is guaranteed when on a tour) or a local person willing to show me around (which relies on me being able to befriend such a person with time on their hands).

Comment: The South (Dixie minus Florida) is an area of 450,000 square miles, an area larger than France, Germany, and the UK put together. So although I have had good experiences with GAdventures, a [9-day tour](http://www.gadventures.com/trips/highlights-of-the-deep-south/NUSH/2014/) means a whole lot of time on the highway traveling from place to place. I would suggest trying to narrow your area of interest. You could probably spend a week in and around New Orleans alone.

Comment: Exactly what choster said. If it's Tennessee you are specifically interested in, there are at least three different sub-cultures. Western Tennessee is exactly like the rest of the South, complete with its own brand of barbecue (the best in the world, by the way), the middle (Nashville) is a lot like Texas (country music mecca), and the eastern part of the state is a lot more like West Virginia and the other Appalachian states. So even there, it depends on what you're after.

Comment: How long is this tour supposed to be? I think you might _need_ a whole year to see the South!

Comment: There's only so much time and money available! I want to see so many other places in the US too but I might have to try and be realistic about what I can fit into one trip... Thanks for all the advice so far guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience with tour groups has generally been guided by two rules of thumb (developed over a fair few organized tours I've gone on):

- The "gap year" style of trips will generally be as cheap as possible, so tend to come from a few dedicated providers, e.g. the famous Contiki tours.
- The "pensioner" trips will often be the more expensive options on a given tour.

As a result I've had luck with the low-end options of mainstream tour providers.  Examples for your criteria with tour providers I've had luck with in the past, include:

- [A southern loop from Atlanta](http://www.peregrineadventures.com/north-america/united-states/deep-south-delta-blues-2014)
- [A New Orleans-Chicago trip that ticks the boxes you mentioned](http://www.intrepidtravel.com/united-states/new-orleans-chicago-69812)

This is based purely off my own anecdotal evidance though, mainly travelling through Africa, Asia and South America.  I have a gut feel that the traveller profile in group trips in the USA may err on the older side simply because younger travellers will tend to "roll their own" trip.

Comment: A 30-ish friend did an Intrepid US one recently (coast to coast) - a variety of ages on the tour, sounded very good, if a lot of driving each day.